# fetch next n records from table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, record

I am currently showing latest top 5 records from table and on click of button want to show next 5 records from table. How can I do this in mysql.

Comment: Please post your current code so that we can help better!

Comment: Your question is too general.  Try showing a small sample of code that demonstrates what you have done, in order to focus the question a bit.

Comment: i am using this query to get first 5 records. I also have a button in my html. on clicking this button i have to fetch next 5 records from table.

$select = "select Post.*, concat(registration.Firstname,' ',registration.Lastname) as Name, about.ProfilePic from post LEFT JOIN about On Post.UserId=About.UserId inner join registration on registration.Id = post.UserId where post.UserId ='".$user."' order by post.PostId desc LIMIT 5";

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) -

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
LIMIT 5,5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var page=1;
// On user button click, increment 'page' variable
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
page++;
//call php function getRecords();
});

function getRecords($page){

$start = 5*$page;
$limit = 5;

// fetch data by following query

SELECT *
FROM `table`
LIMIT $start,$limit

} 
}
```

Above code is flow of logic. There might be some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

We can used

SELECT * FROM `yourtablename` LIMIT nth,5